# Создание личной страницы

Tags: php, html, html5, регистрация

Не выводится в профиле имя пользователя которое было зарегистрировано.
Код личной страницы(куда надо вывести "Имя пользователя"):

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<?php
$title = "Личная страница";
require_once "blocks/head.php"; 
?>

</head>
<body>
<?php require_once "blocks/header.php" ?>
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="/img/noavatar.jpg" width="155" height="120" alt="Аватар" align="left">
<div class="Block">
<?php
echo $_SESSION['USER_NICKNAME'];
?>
</div>

</div>

<?php require_once"blocks/footer.php" ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

===================================================================================
Код страницы регистрации:

```
<?php
//Запускаем сессию
session_start();

//Добавляем файл подключения к БД
require_once("dbconnect.php");

//Объявляем ячейку для добавления ошибок, которые могут возникнуть при обработке формы.
$_SESSION["error_messages"] = '';

//Объявляем ячейку для добавления успешных сообщений
$_SESSION["success_messages"] = '';
/*
Проверяем была ли отправлена форма, то есть была ли нажата кнопка зарегистрироваться. Если да, то идём дальше, если нет, то выведем пользователю сообщение об ошибке, о том что он зашёл на эту страницу напрямую.
*/
if(isset($_POST["btn_submit_register"]) && !empty($_POST["btn_submit_register"])){


/* Проверяем если в глобальном массиве $_POST существуют данные отправленные из формы и заключаем переданные данные в обычные переменные.*/

if(isset($_POST["first_name"])){

//Обрезаем пробелы с начала и с конца строки
$first_name = trim($_POST["first_name"]);

//Проверяем переменную на пустоту
if(!empty($first_name)){
// Для безопасности, преобразуем специальные символы в HTML-сущности
$first_name = htmlspecialchars($first_name, ENT_QUOTES);
}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Укажите Ваше имя</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}


}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Отсутствует поле с именем</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}


if(isset($_POST["nickname"])){

//Обрезаем пробелы с начала и с конца строки
$nickname = trim($_POST["nickname"]);

if(!empty($nickname)){
// Для безопасности, преобразуем специальные символы в HTML-сущности
$nickname = htmlspecialchars($nickname, ENT_QUOTES);


//Проверяем формат полученного почтового адреса с помощью регулярного выражения

$reg_nickname = "/^[_a-zA-Z0-9абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ ]+$/";

if( !preg_match($reg_nickname, $nickname)){
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Вы ввели неправельный Имя пользователя</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

//Проверяем нет ли уже такого адреса в БД.
$result_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `nickname` FROM `users` WHERE `nickname`='".$nickname."'");

//Если кол-во полученных строк ровно единице, значит пользователь с таким именем пользователя уже зарегистрирован
if($result_query->num_rows == 1){

//Если полученный результат не равен false
if(($row = $result_query->fetch_assoc()) != false){

// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Имя пользователя уже занято</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка в запросе к БД</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");
}

/* закрытие выборки */
$result_query->close();

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

/* закрытие выборки */
$result_query->close();

}else{

// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Укажите Ваше имя пользователя</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}


}else{

// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Отсутствует поле с именем пользователя</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}


if(isset($_POST["email"])){

//Обрезаем пробелы с начала и с конца строки
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);

if(!empty($email)){

$email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES);

// (3) Место кода для проверки формата почтового адреса и его уникальности
//Проверяем формат полученного почтового адреса с помощью регулярного выражения
$reg_email = "/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\._-]*[a-z0-9]*@([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i";

//Если формат полученного почтового адреса не соответствует регулярному выражению
if( !preg_match($reg_email, $email)){
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Вы ввели неправельный email</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

//Проверяем нет ли уже такого адреса в БД.
$result_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".$email."'");

//Если кол-во полученных строк ровно единице, значит пользователь с таким почтовым адресом уже зарегистрирован
if($result_query->num_rows == 1){

//Если полученный результат не равен false
if(($row = $result_query->fetch_assoc()) != false){

// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Почтовый адрес уже используется</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка в запросе к БД</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");
}

/* закрытие выборки */
$result_query->close();

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

/* закрытие выборки */
$result_query->close();

}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Укажите Ваш email</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Отсутствует поле для ввода Email</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}


if(isset($_POST["password"])){

//Обрезаем пробелы с начала и с конца строки
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);

if(!empty($password)){
$password = htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES);

//Шифруем папроль
$password = md5($password."top_secret"); 
}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Укажите Ваш пароль</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");


//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}

}else{
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Отсутствует поле для ввода пароля</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}



//Запрос на добавления пользователя в БД
$result_query_insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (first_name, nickname, email, password) VALUES ('".$first_name."', '".$nickname."', '".$email."', '".$password."')");

if(!$result_query_insert){
// Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка запроса на добавления пользователя в БД</p>";

//Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_register.php");

//Останавливаем скрипт
exit();
}else{


//Отправляем пользователя на страницу авторизации
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$address_site."/form_auth.php");
}

/* Завершение запроса */
$result_query_insert->close();

//Закрываем подключение к БД
$mysqli->close();


}else{

exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Вы зашли на эту страницу напрямую, поэтому нет данных для обработки. Вы можете перейти на <a href=".$address_site."> главную страницу </a>.</p>");
}

session_start();
// Генерируем случайное число.
$rand = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

// Сохраняем значение переменной $rand ( капчи ) в сессию
$_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;
$_SESSION['USER_NICKNAME'] = $nickname;
?>
```

Comment: а если после регистрации еще раз обновить страницу?

Comment: А зачем вам два раза session_start? и конечно вроде бы логично было бы попробовать в самом начале после старта сессии записать левый ник и посмотреть может у вас условие не пишет $nickname? при том насколько помню после header он больше не работает

Comment: Ну и без форматирования я вообще не могу прочитать код если честно...

Comment: У вас даже вывода собственных ошибок нет `SESSION['error_message']`, на странице пользователя